# PHP repeat curl request until httpcode 200 is received

Tags: php, curl

I have a simple curl request in PHP like so:

```
$request = curl_init('https://some/path/');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:'.$token));

$response = curl_exec($request);
$errors = curl_error($request);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($request);
```

The url I'm calling will return a 202 if it is still preparing the data and a 200 when it is ready.

How can I build in logic to repeat the request until I receive a 200 response.

Comment: How quickly must you have a 200 response? Are we talking seconds (a user is waiting on a result), or minutes (some background process)?

Comment: Use  a forever loop till you get status code 200

Comment: And does this external API service not have webhooks to utilize?

Comment: so it's a music mixing endpoint, 202 file is created and being added to download url, 200 is file ready to download, it takes about 1 second for every minute of a wav file, so it depends how long the track is

Comment: Surely they would not be pleased if you ran an endless loop hitting the service over and over (think dos attack). I would think they have webhooks somewhere in their api documention to setup and use (where they tell an endpoint on your server when its completed). If they do not... well, hrm. I would only suggest hitting the curl once a minute with a cron then to reduce the overload of hits.

Comment: I'd suggest something like, initiate the file creation call and show a success response to the user if the file is created. Then use an ajax call to check if the download file is ready. When you get a 200 Response, you can display the download URL on the same page. This Ajax call can be repeated at a fixed intervals. 

This is only from the User point of view. Better to utilize the `webhooks` if possible. Ie, when the file is ready for download, the third-party will ping your application with a success message.

Comment: @Ash1271 that could work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, rather than an infinite loop spamming the request I've used `sleep` and `break`, so it will try every 10 seconds for max 1 minute, like so:

```
for($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
    $request = curl_init('https://some/path/');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:'.$token));
    
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    $errors = curl_error($request);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($request);
    
    if($httpcode == 200){
        var_dump($response);
        break;
    }
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: re-creating and deleting the curl handle inside the loop is a waste of cpu though, it will use less cpu if you move curl_init() and curl_close() outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

you could use something similar to this

```
$processCompleted = false;
$interval = 2; //seconds
$request = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:'.$token));

while(!$processCompleted) {
    
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    // Check HTTP status code
    if (!curl_errno($response)) {
        switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($request , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        case 200:  # OK
            ...//do your stuff
            break;
        default:
            sleep($interval);
        }
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}while($httpcode !== 200);
```

note that without a sleep(), it will spam-ask the url, as fast as it can, "is it done? is it done? is it done?" over and over, if you want to sleep when the answer isn't 200, maybe try

```
for(;;){
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpcode===200){break;}
    sleep(1);
}
```